# How do airlines validate a Canadian PR card at Check-In?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada

Airlines and Commercial carriers validate travel documents for passengers before issuing a boarding pass, I'm curious to better understand how this works and if there is an online portal (like timatic) that we as passengers can use as well.

The scenario that I have in mind is if a Canadian Permanent Resident (PR) has two passports from different countries, the PR Card lists only a single nationality if they can use the PR card with the passport whose nationality is not listed on the PR card? This would be necessary if they were departing from Canada from the second country of citizenship which requires them to use the passport issued by the said country.

Comment: Canada has no exit checks at immigration, so leaving Canada isn't the problem. The problem is boarding the flight to Canada from the third country without wanting to disclose the additional citizenship to the third country.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. I'll delete my comment.